# Excluding values from N files based on another file

Tags: linux, awk, grep

I have more than 50 .csv files on a Linux directory, which I will call `/tmp/`.
My intention is to exclude lines from all the files on `/tmp/` when they match the patterns of a specific `/home/Matching.csv` file:

```
cat /home/Matching.csv
C
B
G
```

I'll exemplify `/tmp/` files with `example_file1.csv` and `example_file2.csv`.

```
cat /tmp/example_file1.csv
E,Sunday
B,Saturday
A,Wednesday
D,Tuesday
C,Friday

cat /tmp/example_file2.csv
C,January
G,December
D,August
```

As a result, I would like to see the `/tmp/` files changed to:

```
cat /tmp/example_file1.csv
E,Sunday
A,Wednesday
D,Tuesday

cat /tmp/example_file2.csv
D,August
```

Comment: So `join` the lines. Remember to `sort` them before `join`ing. Do you care about the output sorting order?

Comment: Yes, I do. I've left the unsorted on purpose :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for file in /tmp/*.csv; do
    mv -- "$file" "${file}.bak"
    grep -vf /home/Matching.csv "${file}.bak" > "${file}"
    #If you want to remove original file, uncomment following line
    #rm "${file}.bak"
done
```

That uses patterns given in `/home/Matching.csv`, as specified by `-f` option.
`-v` selects non-matching lines.

Comment: That grep will show me on screen all the values from /tmp/example_file1.csv excluding all the lines with values present on /home/Matching.csv, which is near my needs, but does not fullfill them. What I need is to edit all the /tmp/ files with that kind of "line exclusion".

Comment: Your answer seems to work fine if I need to compare /home/Matching.csv to /tmp/example_file1.csv. However, I'm looking for a way to compare /home/Matching.csv to more than 50 files on /tmp/, and editing them, no matter the name they have.

Comment: Updated, check if it's enough. I was under the impression that every file ended with `.csv`. If not the case, change `/tmp/*.csv` to `/tmp/*`, but that will mess with your /tmp directory.

Comment: Quasimodo, that works like a charm. Thank you very much for your time, sir.